# Freehand painting in Java

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, mouselistener

I've been writing this little painting program thing, but whenever I release the mouse and move to another point on the screen, the line is drawn over there. I tried clearing the points when the mouse has been released, but that deletes everything on screen.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PaintingCanvas extends Canvas implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public PaintingCanvas(int width, int height) {
        setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 2; i++) {
            Point p1 = points.get(i);
            Point p2 = points.get(i + 1);
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        }

    }

    @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        points.add(e.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Why code using AWT components in the millennium?  In Swing you might override a `JComponent` or `JPanel` and add it to a (`JPanel` or a `JApplet` or a..) `JFrame`. 2) `setBounds(..)` Don't do that - use layouts. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `PaintingCanvas .. implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener` No it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

- Call the `super.paint(g);` method first thing in your paint method.
- When the mouse is released, paint the image represented by the points ArrayList to a BufferedImage and then clear the points ArrayList, and then call `repaint()`.
- Draw the BufferedImage in the paint method. before drawing your lines (but check that it's not null first). You do this with the `Graphics#drawImage(Image image, int x, int y, ...)` method.
- Better, re-write this to work in Swing by painting in a JPanel's paintComponent method.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is happening - once you start drawing again, the new points are added after the old ones. Once you paint after that, they are included. You'll need to seperate the different paths from each other.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Path classes? If you are simply drawing discrete lines to a screen, the `GeneralPath` class might be a simple solution.

The [Drawing Arbitrary Shapes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html) tutorial explains how to use these.

Basically, every time the user pressed the mouse (on a `mousePressed` event), you would call the path's `moveTo(x, y)` method. For every segment (replacing what you currently do in the `mouseDragged()` method), you would call the path's `lineTo(x, y)` method.

No matter what, you -definitely- need to handle `mousePressed` or `mouseReleased` events, or both, as you are looking for some way to indicate the start of a new line/path, rather than using the old one.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void jPanel1MouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    points.add(evt.getPoint());

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 2; i++)
    {
         Point p1 = points.get(i);
         Point p2 = points.get(i + 1);

       jPanel1.getGraphics().drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
    }

}
private void jPanel1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    points.clear();
    points.add(evt.getPoint());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a 2d arraylist in which the first array is points added to until you lift up your finger then a new array is added for the second line etc...

Answer (score 0):

Insert a garbage point  `-1,-1` in `points` inside `mouseReleased` method and check for it inside `paint` method and skip that point. Updated code:

```
@Override   
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    points.add(new Point(-1, -1));

}

@Override 
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {

        Point p = points.get(i+1);

        int x2 = p.x;
        int y2 = p.y;

        if ( x2 == -1 || y2 == -1) {
            ++i;
            //continue // Considered bad practice, can play havoc with your system. (source http://xkcd.com/292/ ).
        }
        else {
            p = points.get(i);
            int x1 = p.x;
            int y1 = p.y;
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }
}
```

OP, how it feels to see this question after 3 years? :D